# Maven Configuration Probleme with ECLIPSE Kepler

Tags: java, spring, maven, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-jee

I tried to follow a tutorial but, I got an error with maven right from the first step.

```
    Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:pom:1.2 from           http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,   resolution will 
    not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-
  archiver:pom:1.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/
 plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.pom
```

My pom.xml is as follow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dictionnaire.allemand</groupId>
 <artifactId>translator</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>translator Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>translator</finalName>
 </build>
 </project>
```

i tried many sollutions like

```
   mvn -U install
```

but without success. have you any idea how can i fix this error? im working with eclipse-Kepler for java EE devlopper. and i don't working behind a proxy or a firewall.

here is the content of          http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <parent>
     <artifactId>plexus-components</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
       <version>1.1.18</version>
    </parent>
     <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
     <name>Plexus Archiver Component</name>
    <scm>
    <connection>
     scm:svn:http://svn.codehaus.org/plexus/plexus-components/tags/plexus-         archiver-1.2
     </connection>
     <developerConnection>
     scm:svn:https://svn.codehaus.org/plexus/plexus-components/tags/plexus-         archiver-1.2
     </developerConnection>
     <url>
     http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/plexus/plexus-         components/tags/plexus-archiver-1.2
     </url>
     </scm>
     <properties>
     <useJvmChmod>false</useJvmChmod>
     </properties>
     <contributors>
     <contributor>
     <name>Dan Tran</name>
     </contributor>
     <contributor>
     <name>Richard van der Hoff</name>
     </contributor>
     </contributors>
     <dependencies>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
     <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
     <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.5</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
     <artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1</version>
     </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <build>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.6</version>
     <configuration>
     <systemPropertyVariables>
     <useJvmChmod>${useJvmChmod}</useJvmChmod>
     </systemPropertyVariables>
     </configuration>
     </plugin>
     </plugins>
     </build>
     </project>
```

Comment: Can you open the URL: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.pom from the machine that is running Eclipse?

Comment: If you need to update maven project: Try, using Eclipse, righ-click on the project root node, the a context menu will appear. Select "Maven --> Update Project ..."

Comment: than you for your interest. @Pace i edited the question withe content of  repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/… .

Comment: @Owen i have tried this but the problem persits

Comment: Thanks, but the content of the pom isn't as important.  The error is saying that it cannot to that URL and retrieve that POM so I was thinking it may be a connectivity problem from your build server (the server running maven) and that URL.  It sounds like this is probably not the case?